# Why do my car speakers only play background music when the Aux cord is only partially plugged in

Tags: audio

I've looked it up and the only answers I could find didn't seem right. The background stuff always seems pretty good and voices seem to be canceled out.

I know it's not a left/right channel thing because I tried a song I mixed and the left and right channel are identical  and the speakers still do it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is off-topic. A common mistake made by new members is failing to reading what is [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question. You should become familiar with the site by taking a *[tour]* and reading *[ask]*.

Comment: Interesting question actually, it it _might_ better be suited on [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are hearing the difference between the left and right audio tracks.  Ground is the piece the the 3.5 mm jack that gets plugged in last, so what you are instead hearing is the difference in voltage between one channel and another.  Try making a song truly mono, and listening for the effect.

Comment: Although your answer may be correct, please refrain from answering off-topic questions.